# World WFS layers

Tags: layers, wfs, basemap

Does anybody know if there is a WFS that contains layers for the whole world, like roads, lakes, rivers? I am from Argentina and here we have a site that shows all available IDEs in this country (www.idera.gob.ar). I'd be great to have basic layers in a WFS server. OSM has only WMS.

Comment: NaturalEarth, http://www.naturalearthdata.com/,  has the source data for a WFS. I don't know if someone has running a public WFS with that data. You could set up your own WFS using the NaturalEarth datasets.

Comment: If, instead of WFS, you are able to use VectorTiles, then you could have have a look at this download page: https://openmaptiles.org/downloads/